# How can I stop a function after a certain number of recursive calls?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I need to count recursive calls of a function called happy. I got a hint, I can do it with an auxiliary function. I just cant figure it out, how should i implement it. The recursion should stop when it reaches 1000 calls.

```
digits :: Integer -> [Integer]
digits x 
 | x < 1     = []
 | x == 1    = [1]
 | otherwise = x `mod` 10 : digits (x `div` 10)

squareSum :: [Integer] -> Integer
squareSum (x:xs) = sum (map (^2) (x:xs))

happy :: Integer -> Bool
happy x
 | x == 1 = True
 | otherwise = (happy . squareSum . digits) x

happyNumbers :: [Integer]
happyNumbers = filter happy [1..500]
```

`digits` function gets an integer, and creates a list with its digits.

`squareSum` function squares these digits, and summarizes them.

`happy` is the function where it calls itself over and over, but i need to stop it when it reaches 1000 calls.

Comment: I don't understand the question, perhaps you can explain better what you mean by “stop when it reaches 1000 calls”. Also I think the example could be simplified more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, happy numbers are those where the sequence generated by `happy` converges to 1, so you can return `True`, but *unhappy* numbers are those where the sequence continues forever.  You'd like to return `False`, but right now your code just loops on unhappy numbers.  (For example, `happy 1` returns `True`, but `happy 2` hangs.)

The usual way of doing this is to introduce a new parameter that serves as a countdown.  The hint you were given was to introduce an auxiliary function `happy'` so that you wouldn't have to change the type signature of `happy`.  Try defining:

```
happy :: Integer -> Bool
happy x = happy' 1000 x

happy' :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
happy' countDown x
   | x == 1 = True
   | otherwise = (happy' (countDown - 1) . squareSum . digits) x
```

So far, this "solution" will still run forever, but now you have a `countDown` parameter!  You should be able to add a new guarded case that checks if the `countDown` has expired to return `False`.